# XCOPY is copying the whole directory contents, not just the files and folders mentioned in file

Tags: file, text, xcopy

I am trying to copy a set of files and folders recursively from a directory. The set of files are listed in a text file. Here is my script:

```
set src_folder=C:\Users\mmhuqx\HW
set dst_folder=C:\Unix2Windows
set filelist=C:\Unix2Windows\filelist-tm.txt
echo Origen: %src_folder%
echo Destino: %dst_folder%
echo.

for /f "delims=" %%i in (%filelist%) do (
    xcopy  /s /y "%src_folder%\%%i" "%dst_folder%"
)
```

But When I run the script it copies the entire Directory contents including the files and folders not listed in the text file.

How can I make it work using XCOPY, or is it not possible?

Comment: I've tested your script. It works for me. What does the command line print when you execute the script? Maybe that gives you a pointer.

Comment: Here is the contents of the filelist-tm.txt:

Comment: There is no pointer in particulr. The script copies everything from C:\Users\mmhuqx\HW which is a huge amount of files and folders. But the purpose is to copy only the files mentioned in the text file (filelist-tm.txt). Here is the contents of text file: TOP_LEVEL\MODEM_DEBUG
TOP_LEVEL\MODEM_DEBUG
TOP_LEVEL\MODEM_RELEASE
TOP_LEVEL\MODEM_DEBUG\AENEAS_FW.fls
TOP_LEVEL\MODEM_DEBUG\CDS
TOP_LEVEL\MODEM_DEBUG\nvm_SAM_*.cfg
TOP_LEVEL\MODEM_DEBUG\psi.fls
TOP_LEVEL\MODEM_DEBUG\Platform.axf
TOP_LEVEL\MODEM_DEBUG\PlatforTOP_LEVEL\MODEM_DEBUG
TOP_LEVEL\MODEM_RELEASE
TOP_LEVEL\MODEM_DEBUG\AENEAS_FW

Comment: Are you able to help by saying whats wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Your `filelist-tm.txt` seems to be wrong. It contains for example an entry `TOP_LEVEL\MODEM_DEBUG`. So that directory is copied completely with all its files.

It seems that you only want `TOP_LEVEL\MODEM_DEBUG\AENEAS_FW.fls` to be copied. So your `filelist-tm.txt` should only contain this entry.

Comment: Thanks for you comments. But I am still not sure if I understood what you meant. I want to copy not only the TOP_LEVEL\MODEM_DEBUG\AENEAS_FW.fls file but also the files listed, and keeping the same directory structure while copying. But the script is currently copying everything. Can XCOPY be used to do what I have intended?

Comment: Your script does not keep the directory structure because you let xcopy copy the files to `%dst_folder%`. You maybe can fix this if you change that to `%dst_folder%\%%i`. What I meant in my answer was that your filelist should not contain entries which point to a directory. It should only contain the files you want to be copied.

Comment: I have actually tried this also, leaving all the dir entries out of the text file. But still it does not copy the set of files only, but the whole dir structure. Thanks anyway. Not sure if xcopy is the right tool to do this.